# Как заменить содержимое ячеек таблицы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется такая таблица:

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
        <!-- Стартовый состав -->
  <tr><td>Player1</td><td class="_out">45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player2</td><td class="_out">75</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player3</td><td class="_out">45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player4</td><td></td></tr>
        <!-- Замены -->
  <tr><td>Player5</td><td class="_in">45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player6</td><td class="_in">45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player7</td><td class="_in">75</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Как при помощи jquery поменять текст в ячейках, чтобы привести таблицу к такому виду:

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
        <!-- Стартовый состав -->
  <tr><td>Player1</td><td>(Player5, 45)</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player2</td><td>Player7, 75</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player3</td><td>(Player6, 45)</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player4</td><td></td></tr>
        <!-- Замены -->
  <tr><td>Player5</td><td>45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player6</td><td>45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player7</td><td>75</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const inCells = $('table ._in').get(); 
$('table ._out').each(function () {
  const inIdx = inCells.findIndex(el => el.textContent === this.textContent); 
  if (inIdx < 0) return; 
  const inCell = $(inCells.splice(inIdx, 1)[0]).removeClass('_in'), 
        newText = `(${inCell.prev().text()}, ${inCell.text()})`; 
  $(this).removeClass('_out').text(newText); 
});
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
        <!-- Стартовый состав -->
  <tr><td>Player1</td><td class="_out">45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player2</td><td class="_out">75</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player3</td><td class="_out">45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player4</td><td></td></tr>
        <!-- Замены -->
  <tr><td>Player5</td><td class="_in">45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player6</td><td class="_in">45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Player7</td><td class="_in">75</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так (не забудьте добавить к таблице `id="format"`):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {     
  $("#format ._in").each(function(a){
    var a = $(this);
    var val = $(this).html();
    $("#format ._out").each(function(e){ 
     if ($(this).html() == val){
       var player_in = $(a).parent().find("td:not(._in)").html();
       $(this).html("(" + player_in + ", " + $(this).html() + ")");  
       return false;
     }
    }); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="format">
  <tbody>
    <!-- Стартовый состав -->
    <tr>
      <td>Player1</td>
      <td class="_out">45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player2</td>
      <td class="_out">75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player3</td>
      <td class="_out">45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player4</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Замены -->
    <tr>
      <td>Player5</td>
      <td class="_in">45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player6</td>
      <td class="_in">45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player7</td>
      <td class="_in">75</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Посмотрите работу: 
https://jsfiddle.net/adudnik/L80gv5xj/